# Tools for learning binary file formats

Tags: hex-viewer

Something what will highlight or prettyprint file's internal structure. Like hex editor, but more intelligent. It should either know most common files already, or should be configurable enough.

Something like Wireshark, but for files.

Windows or Linux is fine.

Comment: Look for forensics toolsets.

Answer (score 2):

[101 editor](http://www.sweetscape.com/010editor/) comes with "binary templates" that interpret binary files for you. The [template repository](http://www.sweetscape.com/010editor/repository/templates/) contains templates for >80 binary file formats (as of today).

101 editor is a commercial product, starting at 50$ for home use and 130$ for commercial use. It's available for Windows, Mac and Ubuntu.

Screenshot of binary templates from their website:

[image: Binary template screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

I use my Binary Editor for this kind of task.
Certainly not as pretty as 010 Editor (its a text mode program), but decodes quite a few file formats and is user extendable.
http://www.nyangau.org/be/be.htm

Binary freely redistributable, but not open source.

Comment: Would you mind adding a short example (command line, output) illustrating briefly how the tool can be used to perform what the asker describes? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Hachoir (https://github.com/haypo/hachoir3) is the library to consider.

It is free, open source, is written in Python, installable via `pip install hachoir3`.

Command-line tools using Hachoir parsers:

- hachoir-grep: find a text pattern in a binary file
- hachoir-metadata: get metadata from binary files
- hachoir-strip: modify a file to remove metadata
- hachoir-urwid: display the content of a binary file in text mode and navigate binary formats interactively

For docs, go to https://hachoir3.readthedocs.io/urwid.html.
Disclaimer: no affiliation whatsoever.